# Cell Format of Time being read as General

Tags: excel, epplus

If I have a cell contents as the text: THYSS

Then I format that cell as a Time and read the format name using:

> workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, start.Column].Style.Numberformat.Format

It returns a string "[$-F400]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM"

In the cell the THYSS is displayed.

In the Fx bar THYSS is displayed.

Everything seems reasonable and as expected.

However, If I have a cell contents as: 1.7063

Then I format that cell as a Time and read the format name using:

> workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, start.Column].Style.Numberformat.Format

It returns a string "General"

And in the cell 16:57:04 is displayed.
In the Fx bar 01/01/1900  16:57:04 is displayed.

Why is it returning General?!?!?!?!?!?

I am simply trying to ensure that a spreadsheet to be imported has no Formats to any cells, if it does have formatting then I need to inform the user to correct it, I cannot automatically remove formatting for them.

P.S. Incidentally If I now set the format to General the cell contents have now magically become 1.7062962962963

Comment: has it been set to a number format, as it will be general until number formatting is applied I believe https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Available-number-formats-0afe8f52-97db-41f1-b972-4b46e9f1e8d2

Comment: @Nathan_Sav If what you are saying applies here then a cell containing 1.7063 would say it's Numberformat.Format was Time, and the text (with Time format) would say it's Numberformat.Format was General... Nope, it is set as Time... the issue is if the cell contents are text then Numberformat.Format says [$-F400]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM but if the cell contents are a decimal of 1.7063 then Numberformat.Format says General... erm wtf?!?!?!?

Comment: I think it is Excel adjusting maybe.  If you do as test in time format, and do the following `? typename(activecell.value),typename(activecell.text)` you get `String        String`  the same with midday 12:00:00 in the cell, you get `Double        String` incidentally, neither are of a date type.  So I would say the numberformat is determined by the text value and adjusted accordingly, if cannot be represented.  As `99:99:00` would adhere to the format convention(ish) but still returns as the text entry.

Comment: thinking further, this would be a natural error trapping by Excel, as every time an inconsistent format was reached, the value would be replaced by an error.

Comment: What your saying makes sense, and I thank you for your input... it just seems a daft way to do things... i.e. so there is not a way to reliably detect if General format has been applied by the user, that is there is not a way without a shed load of work to detect all possibilities that may cause a cell formatted one way to report that it is formatted another.

Comment: Seems to be working as expected for me.  I get the time format string you list above.  What version of epplus are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may explain my comments

```
Public Function FormatRange(r As Excel.Range) As Variant

Dim x As Variant

On Error GoTo eHandle:

    If r.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy" Then
        x = CDate(r.Text)
    Else

    End If

Exit Function

eHandle:

    FormatRange = CStr(r.Value)
    r.Value = FormatRange
    r.NumberFormat = "General"


End Function
```

Comment: But wouldn't you then expect cell contents of THYSS with a format of Time to cause an error and be reported as General, and not as "[$-F400]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM" ? ... conversely the 1.7063 is being converted to a time and not (seemingly) causing an error but is being reported as General, when in fact it has a format of Time applied to it.